# Run .py file in Windows ce 5.0

Tags: python

I have created one simple application as(Hello.py) in "JetBrains PyCharm Community Edition 4.5.4". Now i am trying to run this .py file on Windows CE 5.0, I am getting the error as:

Cannot find 'Hello' (or one of it's components). Make sure the path and filename are correct and that all the required libraries are available.

Please tell me the solution what should i do to resolve this error. Do needful.

Thanks & Regards

Rushali Watane

Answer (score -1):

First, make sure that python was installed or not.

after, goto command prompt and run below command:

> python /file_path/Hello.py

Comment: When i have run this command on command prompt, it gives me message as- "Cannot execute python.exe";but when i have check the simple command as (print("Hello World"))on Python Command line, it shows output as Hello World;but same command not working on command prompt. 

Please Tell me what should i do.

Answer (score -1):

I have installed Python 2.5 setup on HMI Windows CE 5.0 with ARM processor. I am sending you screenshot of error screen.[Error Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLBhH.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

yes, In your pc may be default python2 version.But current date it expired.
If you want to run this file go to step by step in cd dir/ dir/ upto pycharm project directory .
Then,
 $ cd project name python filename.py
or for python 3- $ python3 filename.py

Comment: They question is about Windows CE 5, which was released in 2004... Your instructions seems to assume a Unix-like environment....